# Ruby Incorrect link generation redirect_to products_path(@product) generate /products.1 instead of /products/1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to add a reviews on my single product page. But when I click Submit - It takes me to the /products.1 page, instead of /products/1

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
def create
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @comment = @product.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user
    @comment.save

    redirect_to products_path(@product)
end

def destroy

end

private
def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:user_id, :body, :rating)
end
end
```

and the comment.html.erb

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <% if signed_in? %>
      <h4>Add a review:</h4>
      <%= form_for([@product, @product.comments.build]) do |f| %>
        <p>
          <%= f.label :body, "Comment" %><br>
          <%= f.text_area :body, class: "form-control"  %>
        </p>
        <p>
          <%= f.label :rating %><br>
          <%= f.text_field :rating, class: "rating form-control" %>
        </p>  
        <p>
          <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn" %>
        </p>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `redirect_to @product` instead of `redirect_to products_path(@product)`.

Comment: Thanks! I just find out it by myself to))
Yes, it works that way

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your routes.rb under config? Try running rake routes in the terminal and you can debug from there.

Comment: Yes, I see routes.rb and correct link is products/1
I just cannot understand what makes redirect_to products_path(@product) generate products.1

Comment: if you look at the railstutorial.org provided by Michael Hart, https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up, in this section, he explains the concept of using just the object name instead of object_path(@object). That may be your problem.